# My ajax call is not working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi My ajax call is not working in chrome and firefox but it is in Safari.
I am not able to figure it out as it is working on all browsers locally.
My site is recently had SSl certificate.Is that something causing problem?
I am not sure. For reference below is my Ajax function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(function () {

$("#selectReport").hide();
$("select#countryId").change(function () {
    var manu = $("#manufacturerId option:selected").text();
    $("#Manufacturer").val(manu);
    $("#selectReport").show();

});

$("select#reportId").change(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var country = $("#countryId option:selected").text();
    $("#CountryName").val(country);
    });
$("select#reportId").change(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var reportName = $("#reportId option:selected").text();
    var manufacturer = $("#Manufacturer").val();
    var countryName = $("#CountryName").val();
    var theUrl = "/Reports/GetReport/" + reportName + "/" + manufacturer + "/" + countryName;

    $.ajax({
        url: theUrl,
        type: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("I am success");
           $('#ajaxOptionalFields').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("an error occured here");
        }
    });
});
});
//]]>


</script>
```

Comment: Look at the console on the browser. What does it say? Is there a network error? Is there a JavaScript error? You need to debug it.

Comment: In Chrome, right-click on page -> Inspect element -> Console

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(function () {

    $("select#selectReport").hide();
    $("#countryId").change(function () {
        var manu = $("#manufacturerId option:selected").text();
        $("#Manufacturer").val(manu);
          $("#selectReport").show();

    });

Comment: @boerealis It is saying Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not found

Comment: looks like the jquery library hasn't loaded

Comment: How are you loading jQuery into the page? From a CDN, or locally?

Comment: @Moeri I am using highcharts which is not using ssl implementation all the other bits are working but I am not able to display http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js as https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js because it is not exisitng

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you didn't load the Jquery Lib,

http://jquery.com/download/   download Jquery lib and put it in your js folder and load it.. then it should understand what "$" is... in Jquery i always start script like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     //do sth here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying link directly please copy relative paths so that it will be secured.
For example copy http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js in higncharts.js and point that to relative path.